# Removing checkout button container in shopify debut theme | liquid

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid

I am trying to set up a minimum order amount for one product that is not affecting other products. If the minimum order is not met I want to hide the entire checkout button container i.e normal checkout, Paypal and gpay.

I was trying to write some code following this logic:

the product that is meant to have the minimum order amount get's the tag: min10.

I imagined a piece of code in the checkout and cart page that looks something like this:

```
 {% assign show_checkout_button = true %}
  {% for item in cart.items %}
    {% if item.product.tags contains 'min10' and item.quantity <= 9 %}
 {% assign show_checkout_button = false %}
     <p>You will need to purchase at least 10 of the product "{{ item.product.title }}"</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if show_checkout_button %}
   <!-- show checkout button -->
  {% endif %}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. I am unfamiliar with liquid and generally not great at writing code.

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code and how I can actually hide the button container?

I know it's solved like checkoutbtn.ishidden in other languages. how is this done in liquid?

And where exactly would I have to place it?

Thanks in advance! This is doing my head in the entire day already.

```html
<div class="page-width" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="cart-template" data-ajax-enabled="{{ section.settings.cart_ajax_enable }}">

  <div {% if cart.item_count == 0 %}class="hide" {% endif %}data-cart-wrapper>
    <div class="cart-header">
      <h1 class="cart-header__title">{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
      <a href="{{ routes.all_products_collection_url }}" class="text-link text-link--accent">
        {{ 'cart.general.continue_shopping' | t }}
      </a>
    </div>

    <form action="{{ routes.cart_url }}" method="post" novalidate class="cart">
      <table>
        <thead class="cart__row cart__row--heading">
          <th scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.product' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-right" scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.price' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-right small--hide" scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-right small--hide" scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.total' | t }}</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-cart-line-items>
          {%- for item in cart.items -%}
            <tr class="cart__row" data-cart-item data-cart-item-key="{{ item.key }}" data-cart-item-url="{{ item.url }}" data-cart-item-title="{{ item.title }}" data-cart-item-index="{{ forloop.index }}" data-cart-item-quantity="{{ item.quantity }}">
              <td class="cart__meta small--text-left" data-cart-table-cell>
                <div class="cart__product-information">
                  <div class="cart__image-wrapper">
                    <img class="cart__image{% if item.image == null %} hide{% endif %}" src="{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item | img_url: 'x190' }}{% endcomment %}{%- capture LS_IMG_URL -%}{%- render "ls-img-url", image: item, img_url: 'x190' -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_IMG_URL }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}" alt="{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.image.alt | escape }}{% endcomment %}{%- capture LS_ALT -%}{%- render "ls-alt", image: item.image -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_ALT | escape }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}" data-cart-item-image>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="list-view-item__title">
                      <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="cart__product-title" data-cart-item-title>
                        {{ item.product.title }}
<span class='booster-cart-item-success-notes' data-key='{{item.key}}'></span><span class='booster-cart-item-upsell-notes' data-key='{{item.key}}'></span>
                      </a>
                    </div>

                    {%- assign variant_options = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                    {%- if item.product.has_only_default_variant != true -%}
                      {%- assign variant_options = item.options_with_values -%}
                    {%- endif -%}
                    {%- assign property_size = item.properties | size -%}

                    <ul class="product-details{% if item.product.has_only_default_variant and property_size == 0 %} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-details aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.product_details' | t }}">
                      {%- for option in variant_options -%}
                        <li class="product-details__item product-details__item--variant-option{% if item.product.has_only_default_variant %} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-option>{{ option.name }}: {{ option.value }}</li>
                      {%- endfor -%}

                      {%- comment -%}
                        Optional, loop through custom product line items if available

                        Line item properties come in as having two parts. The first part will be passed with the default form,
                        but p.last is the actual custom property and may be blank. If it is, don't show it.

                        For more info on line item properties, visit:
                          - http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization
                      {%- endcomment -%}

                      {%- assign properties = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                      {%- if property_size > 0 -%}
                        {%- assign properties = item.properties -%}
                      {%- endif -%}

                      {%- for p in properties -%}
                        {%- unless p.last == blank -%}
                          <li class="product-details__item product-details__item--property{%if property_size == 0%} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-property>
                            <span class="product-details__item-label" data-cart-item-property-name>{{ p.first }}: </span>

                            {%- comment -%}
                              Check if there was an uploaded file associated
                            {%- endcomment -%}
                            <span data-cart-item-property-value>
                              {%- if p.last contains '/uploads/' -%}
                                <a href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
                              {%- else -%}
                                {{ p.last }}
                              {%- endif -%}
                            </span>
                          </li>
                        {%- endunless -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    </ul>

                    <p class="cart__remove">
                      <a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" class="text-link text-link--accent" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.remove' | t: product: item.title }}" data-cart-remove>{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__price text-right">

                {%- assign hasDiscount = false -%}
                {%- if item.original_price != item.final_price -%}
                  {%- assign hasDiscount = true -%}
                {%- endif -%}

                <div data-cart-item-price>
                  <dl data-cart-item-price-list>
                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for discount item
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% unless hasDiscount %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-cart-item-discounted-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <s data-cart-item-original-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.original_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</s>
                      </dd>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.sale_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <span class="order-discount" data-cart-item-final-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.final_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.final_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                      </dd>
                    </div>

                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for regular price item
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% if hasDiscount %}class="hide" {% endif %}data-cart-item-regular-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd data-cart-item-regular-price>
                        {% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.original_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}
                      </dd>
                    </div>

                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for unit price
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% unless item.unit_price_measurement %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-unit-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">{{ 'products.product.unit_price_label' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <span class="price-unit-price">
                          {%- capture unit_price_separator -%}
                            <span aria-hidden="true">/</span><span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.unit_price_separator' | t }}&nbsp;</span>
                          {%- endcapture -%}
                          {%- capture unit_price_base_unit -%}
                            {%- if item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value != 1 -%}
                              {{- item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value -}}
                            {%- endif -%}
                            {{ item.unit_price_measurement.reference_unit }}
                          {%- endcapture -%}

                          <span data-unit-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.unit_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.unit_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>{{- unit_price_separator -}}<span data-unit-price-base-unit>{{- unit_price_base_unit -}}</span>
                        </span>
                      </dd>
                    </div>
                  </dl>
                </div>

                {%- assign itemDiscounts = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                {%- if item.line_level_discount_allocations != blank -%}
                  {%- assign itemDiscounts = item.line_level_discount_allocations -%}
                {%- endif -%}

                <ul class="order-discount order-discount--list order-discount--title order-discount--cart{% if item.line_level_discount_allocations == blank %} hide{% endif %}" aria-label="{{ 'customer.order.discount' | t }}" data-cart-item-discount-list>
                  {%- for discount_allocation in itemDiscounts -%}
                    <li class="order-discount__item" data-cart-item-discount>
                      {% include 'icon-saletag' %}
                      <span data-cart-item-discount-title>
                        {{- discount_allocation.discount_application.title -}}
                      </span> (-<span data-cart-item-discount-amount>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ discount_allocation.amount | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = discount_allocation.amount -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>)
                    </li>
                  {%- endfor -%}
                </ul>

                <div class="cart__qty medium-up--hide">
                  <label for="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}" data-quantity-label-mobile>
                    {{ 'cart.label.qty' | t }}
                  </label>
                  <input id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                    value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-mobile>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__qty-error-message-wrapper cart__qty-error-message-wrapper--mobile hide" role="alert" data-cart-quantity-error-message-wrapper>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                  {% include 'icon-error' %}
                  <span class="cart__qty-error-message" data-cart-quantity-error-message></span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__quantity-td text-right small--hide">
                <div class="cart__qty">
                  <label for="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" data-quantity-label-desktop>{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</label>
                  <input id="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                    name="updates[]" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-desktop>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__qty-error-message-wrapper cart__qty-error-message-wrapper--desktop hide" role="alert" data-cart-quantity-error-message-wrapper>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                  {% include 'icon-error' %}
                  <span class="cart__qty-error-message" data-cart-quantity-error-message></span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__final-price text-right small--hide" data-cart-item-line-price>
                {%- comment -%}
                  Markup template for discount item
                {%- endcomment -%}
                <dl {% unless item.original_line_price != item.final_line_price %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-cart-item-discounted-price-group>
                  <dt>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'cart.label.regular_total' | t }}</span>
                  </dt>
                  <dd>
                    <s data-cart-item-original-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.original_line_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_line_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</s>
                  </dd>
                  <dt>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'cart.label.discounted_total' | t }}</span>
                  </dt>
                  <dd>
                    <span class="order-discount" data-cart-item-final-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.final_line_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.final_line_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                  </dd>
                </dl >

                {%- comment -%}
                  Markup template for regular price item
                {%- endcomment -%}
                <div {% if item.original_line_price != item.final_line_price %}class="hide" {% endif %}data-cart-item-regular-price-group>
                  <span data-cart-item-regular-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}<span class='booster-cart-item-line-price' data-key='{{item.key}}'>{{ item.original_line_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_line_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}</span>{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          {%- endfor -%}

         
          
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="cart__footer">
        <div class="grid">
          {%- if section.settings.cart_notes_enable -%}
            <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half cart-note">
              <label for="CartSpecialInstructions" class="cart-note__label small--text-center">{{ 'cart.general.note' | t }}</label>
              <textarea name="note" id="CartSpecialInstructions" class="cart-note__input" data-cart-notes>{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
            </div>
          {%- endif -%}
          <div class="grid__item text-right small--text-center{% if section.settings.cart_notes_enable %} medium-up--one-half{% endif %}">

            {%- assign cartDiscounts = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
            {%- if cart.cart_level_discount_applications.size > 0 -%}
              {%- assign cartDiscounts = cart.cart_level_discount_applications -%}
            {%- endif -%}
            <div{% if cart.cart_level_discount_applications.size == 0 %} class="hide"{% endif %} data-cart-discount-wrapper>
              <div class="order-discount-card-wrapper" data-cart-discount>
                {%- for discount_application in cartDiscounts -%}
                  <span class="order-discount order-discount--title order-discount--cart">
                    {% include 'icon-saletag' %}<span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.order.discount' | t }}:</span><span data-cart-discount-title>{{- discount_application.title -}}</span>
                  </span>
                  <span class="order-discount order-discount--cart order-discount--cart-total">
                    -<span data-cart-discount-amount>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ discount_application.total_allocated_amount | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = discount_application.total_allocated_amount -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                  </span>
                {%- endfor -%}
              </div>
            </div>

            
            
            

            <div class="cart-subtotal">
              <span class="cart-subtotal__title">{{ 'cart.general.subtotal' | t }}</span>
              <span class="cart-subtotal__price" data-cart-subtotal>{% comment ls-rpl %}<span class="wh-original-cart-total"><span class='wh-original-price'>{{ cart.total_price | money_with_currency }}</span></span><span class="wh-cart-total"></span><div class="additional-notes"><span class="wh-minimums-note"></span><span class="wh-extra-note"></span></div>{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = cart.total_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money_with_currency" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
            </div>



            {%- capture taxes_shipping_checkout -%}
              {%- if shop.taxes_included and shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_included_and_shipping_policy_html' | t: link: shop.shipping_policy.url }}
              {%- elsif shop.taxes_included -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_included_but_shipping_at_checkout' | t }}
              {%- elsif shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_and_shipping_policy_at_checkout_html' | t: link: shop.shipping_policy.url }}
              {%- else -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_and_shipping_at_checkout' | t }}
              {%- endif -%}
            {%- endcapture -%}
            <div class="cart__shipping rte">{{ taxes_shipping_checkout }}</div>
            <div class="cart__buttons-container">
              <div class="cart__submit-controls">
                {%- unless section.settings.cart_ajax_enable -%}
                <input type="submit" name="update"
                  class="cart__submit btn btn--secondary"
                  value="{{ 'cart.general.update' | t }}">
                {%- endunless -%}
                <input type="submit" name="checkout"
                  class="cart__submit btn btn--small-wide"
                  value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}">
              </div>

              <div class="cart__error-message-wrapper hide" role="alert" data-cart-error-message-wrapper>
                <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                {% include 'icon-error' %}
                <span class="cart__error-message" data-cart-error-message></span>
              </div>

              {%- if additional_checkout_buttons -%}
                <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <p class="visually-hidden" data-cart-status
      aria-live="polite"
      role="status"
    ></p>
  </div>

  <div class="empty-page-content{% if cart.item_count > 0 %} hide{% endif %} text-center" data-empty-page-content>
    <h1>{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
    <p class="cart--empty-message">{{ 'cart.general.empty' | t }}</p>
    <div class="cookie-message">
      <p>{{ 'cart.general.cookies_required' | t }}</p>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ routes.root_url }}" class="btn btn--has-icon-after cart__continue-btn">{{ 'general.404.link' | t }}{% include 'icon-arrow-right' %}</a>
  </div>
</div>



{% schema %}
{
  "name": {
    "da": "Side med indkøbskurv",
    "de": "Warenkorb-Seite",
    "en": "Cart page",
    "es": "Página del carrito de compras",
    "fi": "Ostoskorisivu",
    "fr": "Page du panier",
    "hi": "कार्ट पेज",
    "it": "Pagina del carrello",
    "ja": "カートページ",
    "ko": "카트 페이지",
    "nb": "Handlekurvside",
    "nl": "Winkelwagenpagina",
    "pt-BR": "Página do carrinho",
    "pt-PT": "Página do carrinho",
    "sv": "Varukorgssida",
    "th": "หน้าตะกร้าสินค้า",
    "zh-CN": "购物车页面",
    "zh-TW": "購物車頁面"
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "cart_ajax_enable",
      "label": {
        "da": "Aktivér automatisk opdatering af indkøbskurv",
        "de": "Automatische Warenkorbaktualisierungen aktivieren",
        "en": "Enable automatic cart updates",
        "es": "Habilitar las actualizaciones automáticas del carrito de compra",
        "fi": "Ota automaattinen ostoskorin päivitykset käyttöön",
        "fr": "Activer les mises à jour automatiques",
        "hi": "स्वचालित कार्ट अपडेट सक्षम करें",
        "it": "Abilita aggiornamenti automatici carrello",
        "ja": "自動カートの更新を有効にする",
        "ko": "자동 카트 업데이트 활성화하기",
        "nb": "Aktiver automatiske oppdateringer av handlekurven",
        "nl": "Automatische winkelwagen-updates inschakelen",
        "pt-BR": "Permitir atualizações automáticas do carrinho",
        "pt-PT": "Ativar atualizações automáticas do carrinho",
        "sv": "Aktivera automatiska uppdateringar av varukorgen",
        "th": "เปิดใช้งานการอัปเดตตะกร้าสินค้าอัตโนมัติ",
        "zh-CN": "启用购物车自动更新功能",
        "zh-TW": "啟用自動更新購物車"
      },
      "info": {
        "da": "Opdaterer indkøbskurven, så snart kunden foretager ændringer",
        "de": "Aktualisiert den Warenkorb, sobald Kundenänderungen vorgenommen werden",
        "en": "Updates the cart as soon as customer changes are made",
        "es": "Actualiza el carrito de compra tan pronto como el cliente realice cambios",
        "fi": "Päivittää ostoskorin heti, kun asiakkaan muutokset on tehty",
        "fr": "Mise à jour du panier dès que les modifications apportées aux clients ont été effectuées",
        "hi": "ग्राहक के द्वारा परिवर्तन करते ही कार्ट को अपडेट हो जाता है",
        "it": "Aggiorna il carrello appena il cliente apporta le modifiche",
        "ja": "お客様が変更されるとすぐにカートを更新します",
        "ko": "고객 변경 시 카트를 업데이트합니다.",
        "nb": "Oppdaterer handlekurven så snart kundens endringer er gjort",
        "nl": "De winkelwagen wordt bijgewerkt zodra de klant wijzigingen aanbrengt",
        "pt-BR": "Atualiza o carrinho assim que o cliente faz alterações",
        "pt-PT": "Atualiza o carrinho assim que o cliente faz alterações",
        "sv": "Uppdaterar varukorgen så snart kundändringar görs",
        "th": "อัปเดตตะกร้าสินค้าเมื่อลูกค้าได้ทำการเปลี่ยนแปลง",
        "zh-CN": "客户做出更改后立即更新购物车",
        "zh-TW": "在顧客進行變更時立即更新購物車"
      },
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "cart_notes_enable",
      "label": {
        "da": "Aktivér bemærkninger til indkøbskurv",
        "de": "Warenkorb-Notifikationen erlauben",
        "en": "Enable cart notes",
        "es": "Habilitar notas de carrito",
        "fi": "Ota ostoskorin huomautukset käyttöön",
        "fr": "Activer les notes de panier",
        "hi": "कार्ट नोट्स सक्षम करें",
        "it": "Abilita note carrello",
        "ja": "カートメモを有効にする",
        "ko": "카트 참고 사항 사용",
        "nb": "Aktiver handlekurvmerknader",
        "nl": "Opmerkingen voor winkelwagen inschakelen",
        "pt-BR": "Habilitar observações do carrinho",
        "pt-PT": "Ativar notas do carrinho",
        "sv": "Aktivera varukorgsmeddelanden",
        "th": "เปิดใช้หมายเหตุของตะกร้าสินค้า",
        "zh-CN": "启用购物车备注",
        "zh-TW": "啟用購物車備註"
      },
      "default": false
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: Your code is correct. If you place your code in `cart-template.liquid` it should work perfectly. Can you provide the whole template file content?

Comment: Sure thing. I have added the cart code to the original post

Comment: Your code is missing your conditions

Comment: I have removed them again because they haven't worked they way i wanted them to.
Can you tell me where exactly would I have to insert them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code should be changed to something like that:

```html
<div class="page-width" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="cart-template" data-ajax-enabled="{{ section.settings.cart_ajax_enable }}">

  <div {% if cart.item_count == 0 %}class="hide" {% endif %}data-cart-wrapper>
    <div class="cart-header">
      <h1 class="cart-header__title">{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
      <a href="{{ routes.all_products_collection_url }}" class="text-link text-link--accent">
        {{ 'cart.general.continue_shopping' | t }}
      </a>
    </div>

    <form action="{{ routes.cart_url }}" method="post" novalidate class="cart">
      <table>
        <thead class="cart__row cart__row--heading">
          <th scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.product' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-right" scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.price' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-right small--hide" scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</th>
          <th class="text-right small--hide" scope="col">{{ 'cart.label.total' | t }}</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-cart-line-items>
          {% assign show_checkout_button = true %}
          {%- for item in cart.items -%}
            <tr class="cart__row" data-cart-item data-cart-item-key="{{ item.key }}" data-cart-item-url="{{ item.url }}" data-cart-item-title="{{ item.title }}" data-cart-item-index="{{ forloop.index }}" data-cart-item-quantity="{{ item.quantity }}">
              <td class="cart__meta small--text-left" data-cart-table-cell>
                <div class="cart__product-information">
                  <div class="cart__image-wrapper">
                    <img class="cart__image{% if item.image == null %} hide{% endif %}" src="{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item | img_url: 'x190' }}{% endcomment %}{%- capture LS_IMG_URL -%}{%- render "ls-img-url", image: item, img_url: 'x190' -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_IMG_URL }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}" alt="{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.image.alt | escape }}{% endcomment %}{%- capture LS_ALT -%}{%- render "ls-alt", image: item.image -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_ALT | escape }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}" data-cart-item-image>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="list-view-item__title">
                      <a href="{{ item.url }}" class="cart__product-title" data-cart-item-title>
                        {{ item.product.title }}
<span class='booster-cart-item-success-notes' data-key='{{item.key}}'></span><span class='booster-cart-item-upsell-notes' data-key='{{item.key}}'></span>
                      </a>
                      {% if item.product.tags contains 'min10' and item.quantity <= 9 %}
                        {% assign show_checkout_button = false %}
                        <p>You will need to purchase at least 10 of the product "{{ item.product.title }}"</p>
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>

                    {%- assign variant_options = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                    {%- if item.product.has_only_default_variant != true -%}
                      {%- assign variant_options = item.options_with_values -%}
                    {%- endif -%}
                    {%- assign property_size = item.properties | size -%}

                    <ul class="product-details{% if item.product.has_only_default_variant and property_size == 0 %} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-details aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.product_details' | t }}">
                      {%- for option in variant_options -%}
                        <li class="product-details__item product-details__item--variant-option{% if item.product.has_only_default_variant %} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-option>{{ option.name }}: {{ option.value }}</li>
                      {%- endfor -%}

                      {%- comment -%}
                        Optional, loop through custom product line items if available

                        Line item properties come in as having two parts. The first part will be passed with the default form,
                        but p.last is the actual custom property and may be blank. If it is, don't show it.

                        For more info on line item properties, visit:
                          - http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization
                      {%- endcomment -%}

                      {%- assign properties = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                      {%- if property_size > 0 -%}
                        {%- assign properties = item.properties -%}
                      {%- endif -%}

                      {%- for p in properties -%}
                        {%- unless p.last == blank -%}
                          <li class="product-details__item product-details__item--property{%if property_size == 0%} hide{% endif %}" data-cart-item-property>
                            <span class="product-details__item-label" data-cart-item-property-name>{{ p.first }}: </span>

                            {%- comment -%}
                              Check if there was an uploaded file associated
                            {%- endcomment -%}
                            <span data-cart-item-property-value>
                              {%- if p.last contains '/uploads/' -%}
                                <a href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
                              {%- else -%}
                                {{ p.last }}
                              {%- endif -%}
                            </span>
                          </li>
                        {%- endunless -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}
                    </ul>

                    <p class="cart__remove">
                      <a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" class="text-link text-link--accent" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.remove' | t: product: item.title }}" data-cart-remove>{{ 'cart.general.remove' | t }}</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__price text-right">

                {%- assign hasDiscount = false -%}
                {%- if item.original_price != item.final_price -%}
                  {%- assign hasDiscount = true -%}
                {%- endif -%}

                <div data-cart-item-price>
                  <dl data-cart-item-price-list>
                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for discount item
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% unless hasDiscount %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-cart-item-discounted-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <s data-cart-item-original-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.original_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</s>
                      </dd>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.sale_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <span class="order-discount" data-cart-item-final-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.final_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.final_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                      </dd>
                    </div>

                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for regular price item
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% if hasDiscount %}class="hide" {% endif %}data-cart-item-regular-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd data-cart-item-regular-price>
                        {% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.original_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}
                      </dd>
                    </div>

                    {%- comment -%}
                      Markup template for unit price
                    {%- endcomment -%}
                    <div {% unless item.unit_price_measurement %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-unit-price-group>
                      <dt>
                        <span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">{{ 'products.product.unit_price_label' | t }}</span>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <span class="price-unit-price">
                          {%- capture unit_price_separator -%}
                            <span aria-hidden="true">/</span><span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.unit_price_separator' | t }}&nbsp;</span>
                          {%- endcapture -%}
                          {%- capture unit_price_base_unit -%}
                            {%- if item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value != 1 -%}
                              {{- item.unit_price_measurement.reference_value -}}
                            {%- endif -%}
                            {{ item.unit_price_measurement.reference_unit }}
                          {%- endcapture -%}

                          <span data-unit-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.unit_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.unit_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>{{- unit_price_separator -}}<span data-unit-price-base-unit>{{- unit_price_base_unit -}}</span>
                        </span>
                      </dd>
                    </div>
                  </dl>
                </div>

                {%- assign itemDiscounts = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
                {%- if item.line_level_discount_allocations != blank -%}
                  {%- assign itemDiscounts = item.line_level_discount_allocations -%}
                {%- endif -%}

                <ul class="order-discount order-discount--list order-discount--title order-discount--cart{% if item.line_level_discount_allocations == blank %} hide{% endif %}" aria-label="{{ 'customer.order.discount' | t }}" data-cart-item-discount-list>
                  {%- for discount_allocation in itemDiscounts -%}
                    <li class="order-discount__item" data-cart-item-discount>
                      {% include 'icon-saletag' %}
                      <span data-cart-item-discount-title>
                        {{- discount_allocation.discount_application.title -}}
                      </span> (-<span data-cart-item-discount-amount>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ discount_allocation.amount | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = discount_allocation.amount -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>)
                    </li>
                  {%- endfor -%}
                </ul>

                <div class="cart__qty medium-up--hide">
                  <label for="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}" data-quantity-label-mobile>
                    {{ 'cart.label.qty' | t }}
                  </label>
                  <input id="updates_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                    value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-mobile>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__qty-error-message-wrapper cart__qty-error-message-wrapper--mobile hide" role="alert" data-cart-quantity-error-message-wrapper>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                  {% include 'icon-error' %}
                  <span class="cart__qty-error-message" data-cart-quantity-error-message></span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__quantity-td text-right small--hide">
                <div class="cart__qty">
                  <label for="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" data-quantity-label-desktop>{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</label>
                  <input id="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                    name="updates[]" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-desktop>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__qty-error-message-wrapper cart__qty-error-message-wrapper--desktop hide" role="alert" data-cart-quantity-error-message-wrapper>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                  {% include 'icon-error' %}
                  <span class="cart__qty-error-message" data-cart-quantity-error-message></span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="cart__final-price text-right small--hide" data-cart-item-line-price>
                {%- comment -%}
                  Markup template for discount item
                {%- endcomment -%}
                <dl {% unless item.original_line_price != item.final_line_price %}class="hide" {% endunless %}data-cart-item-discounted-price-group>
                  <dt>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'cart.label.regular_total' | t }}</span>
                  </dt>
                  <dd>
                    <s data-cart-item-original-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.original_line_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_line_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</s>
                  </dd>
                  <dt>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'cart.label.discounted_total' | t }}</span>
                  </dt>
                  <dd>
                    <span class="order-discount" data-cart-item-final-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ item.final_line_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.final_line_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                  </dd>
                </dl >

                {%- comment -%}
                  Markup template for regular price item
                {%- endcomment -%}
                <div {% if item.original_line_price != item.final_line_price %}class="hide" {% endif %}data-cart-item-regular-price-group>
                  <span data-cart-item-regular-price>{% comment ls-rpl %}<span class='booster-cart-item-line-price' data-key='{{item.key}}'>{{ item.original_line_price | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = item.original_line_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}</span>{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          {%- endfor -%}

         
          
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="cart__footer">
        <div class="grid">
          {%- if section.settings.cart_notes_enable -%}
            <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half cart-note">
              <label for="CartSpecialInstructions" class="cart-note__label small--text-center">{{ 'cart.general.note' | t }}</label>
              <textarea name="note" id="CartSpecialInstructions" class="cart-note__input" data-cart-notes>{{ cart.note }}</textarea>
            </div>
          {%- endif -%}
          <div class="grid__item text-right small--text-center{% if section.settings.cart_notes_enable %} medium-up--one-half{% endif %}">

            {%- assign cartDiscounts = 'template ' | split: ' ' -%}
            {%- if cart.cart_level_discount_applications.size > 0 -%}
              {%- assign cartDiscounts = cart.cart_level_discount_applications -%}
            {%- endif -%}
            <div{% if cart.cart_level_discount_applications.size == 0 %} class="hide"{% endif %} data-cart-discount-wrapper>
              <div class="order-discount-card-wrapper" data-cart-discount>
                {%- for discount_application in cartDiscounts -%}
                  <span class="order-discount order-discount--title order-discount--cart">
                    {% include 'icon-saletag' %}<span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'customer.order.discount' | t }}:</span><span data-cart-discount-title>{{- discount_application.title -}}</span>
                  </span>
                  <span class="order-discount order-discount--cart order-discount--cart-total">
                    -<span data-cart-discount-amount>{% comment ls-rpl %}{{ discount_application.total_allocated_amount | money }}{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = discount_application.total_allocated_amount -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
                  </span>
                {%- endfor -%}
              </div>
            </div>

            
            
            

            <div class="cart-subtotal">
              <span class="cart-subtotal__title">{{ 'cart.general.subtotal' | t }}</span>
              <span class="cart-subtotal__price" data-cart-subtotal>{% comment ls-rpl %}<span class="wh-original-cart-total"><span class='wh-original-price'>{{ cart.total_price | money_with_currency }}</span></span><span class="wh-cart-total"></span><div class="additional-notes"><span class="wh-minimums-note"></span><span class="wh-extra-note"></span></div>{% endcomment %}{%- assign LS_AMOUNT = cart.total_price -%}{%- capture LS_PRICE -%}{%- render "ls-price", price: LS_AMOUNT, filter: "money_with_currency" -%}{%- endcapture -%}{{ LS_PRICE }}{% comment /ls-rpl %}{% endcomment %}</span>
            </div>



            {%- capture taxes_shipping_checkout -%}
              {%- if shop.taxes_included and shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_included_and_shipping_policy_html' | t: link: shop.shipping_policy.url }}
              {%- elsif shop.taxes_included -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_included_but_shipping_at_checkout' | t }}
              {%- elsif shop.shipping_policy.body != blank -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_and_shipping_policy_at_checkout_html' | t: link: shop.shipping_policy.url }}
              {%- else -%}
                {{ 'cart.general.taxes_and_shipping_at_checkout' | t }}
              {%- endif -%}
            {%- endcapture -%}
            <div class="cart__shipping rte">{{ taxes_shipping_checkout }}</div>
            <div class="cart__buttons-container">
              <div class="cart__submit-controls">
                {%- unless section.settings.cart_ajax_enable -%}
                <input type="submit" name="update"
                  class="cart__submit btn btn--secondary"
                  value="{{ 'cart.general.update' | t }}">
                {%- endunless -%}
                {% if show_checkout_button %}
                <input type="submit" name="checkout"
                  class="cart__submit btn btn--small-wide"
                  value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}">
                {% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class="cart__error-message-wrapper hide" role="alert" data-cart-error-message-wrapper>
                <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span>
                {% include 'icon-error' %}
                <span class="cart__error-message" data-cart-error-message></span>
              </div>

              {%- if additional_checkout_buttons and show_checkout_button -%}
                <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <p class="visually-hidden" data-cart-status
      aria-live="polite"
      role="status"
    ></p>
  </div>

  <div class="empty-page-content{% if cart.item_count > 0 %} hide{% endif %} text-center" data-empty-page-content>
    <h1>{{ 'cart.general.title' | t }}</h1>
    <p class="cart--empty-message">{{ 'cart.general.empty' | t }}</p>
    <div class="cookie-message">
      <p>{{ 'cart.general.cookies_required' | t }}</p>
    </div>
    <a href="{{ routes.root_url }}" class="btn btn--has-icon-after cart__continue-btn">{{ 'general.404.link' | t }}{% include 'icon-arrow-right' %}</a>
  </div>
</div>



{% schema %}
{
  "name": {
    "da": "Side med indkøbskurv",
    "de": "Warenkorb-Seite",
    "en": "Cart page",
    "es": "Página del carrito de compras",
    "fi": "Ostoskorisivu",
    "fr": "Page du panier",
    "hi": "कार्ट पेज",
    "it": "Pagina del carrello",
    "ja": "カートページ",
    "ko": "카트 페이지",
    "nb": "Handlekurvside",
    "nl": "Winkelwagenpagina",
    "pt-BR": "Página do carrinho",
    "pt-PT": "Página do carrinho",
    "sv": "Varukorgssida",
    "th": "หน้าตะกร้าสินค้า",
    "zh-CN": "购物车页面",
    "zh-TW": "購物車頁面"
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "cart_ajax_enable",
      "label": {
        "da": "Aktivér automatisk opdatering af indkøbskurv",
        "de": "Automatische Warenkorbaktualisierungen aktivieren",
        "en": "Enable automatic cart updates",
        "es": "Habilitar las actualizaciones automáticas del carrito de compra",
        "fi": "Ota automaattinen ostoskorin päivitykset käyttöön",
        "fr": "Activer les mises à jour automatiques",
        "hi": "स्वचालित कार्ट अपडेट सक्षम करें",
        "it": "Abilita aggiornamenti automatici carrello",
        "ja": "自動カートの更新を有効にする",
        "ko": "자동 카트 업데이트 활성화하기",
        "nb": "Aktiver automatiske oppdateringer av handlekurven",
        "nl": "Automatische winkelwagen-updates inschakelen",
        "pt-BR": "Permitir atualizações automáticas do carrinho",
        "pt-PT": "Ativar atualizações automáticas do carrinho",
        "sv": "Aktivera automatiska uppdateringar av varukorgen",
        "th": "เปิดใช้งานการอัปเดตตะกร้าสินค้าอัตโนมัติ",
        "zh-CN": "启用购物车自动更新功能",
        "zh-TW": "啟用自動更新購物車"
      },
      "info": {
        "da": "Opdaterer indkøbskurven, så snart kunden foretager ændringer",
        "de": "Aktualisiert den Warenkorb, sobald Kundenänderungen vorgenommen werden",
        "en": "Updates the cart as soon as customer changes are made",
        "es": "Actualiza el carrito de compra tan pronto como el cliente realice cambios",
        "fi": "Päivittää ostoskorin heti, kun asiakkaan muutokset on tehty",
        "fr": "Mise à jour du panier dès que les modifications apportées aux clients ont été effectuées",
        "hi": "ग्राहक के द्वारा परिवर्तन करते ही कार्ट को अपडेट हो जाता है",
        "it": "Aggiorna il carrello appena il cliente apporta le modifiche",
        "ja": "お客様が変更されるとすぐにカートを更新します",
        "ko": "고객 변경 시 카트를 업데이트합니다.",
        "nb": "Oppdaterer handlekurven så snart kundens endringer er gjort",
        "nl": "De winkelwagen wordt bijgewerkt zodra de klant wijzigingen aanbrengt",
        "pt-BR": "Atualiza o carrinho assim que o cliente faz alterações",
        "pt-PT": "Atualiza o carrinho assim que o cliente faz alterações",
        "sv": "Uppdaterar varukorgen så snart kundändringar görs",
        "th": "อัปเดตตะกร้าสินค้าเมื่อลูกค้าได้ทำการเปลี่ยนแปลง",
        "zh-CN": "客户做出更改后立即更新购物车",
        "zh-TW": "在顧客進行變更時立即更新購物車"
      },
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "cart_notes_enable",
      "label": {
        "da": "Aktivér bemærkninger til indkøbskurv",
        "de": "Warenkorb-Notifikationen erlauben",
        "en": "Enable cart notes",
        "es": "Habilitar notas de carrito",
        "fi": "Ota ostoskorin huomautukset käyttöön",
        "fr": "Activer les notes de panier",
        "hi": "कार्ट नोट्स सक्षम करें",
        "it": "Abilita note carrello",
        "ja": "カートメモを有効にする",
        "ko": "카트 참고 사항 사용",
        "nb": "Aktiver handlekurvmerknader",
        "nl": "Opmerkingen voor winkelwagen inschakelen",
        "pt-BR": "Habilitar observações do carrinho",
        "pt-PT": "Ativar notas do carrinho",
        "sv": "Aktivera varukorgsmeddelanden",
        "th": "เปิดใช้หมายเหตุของตะกร้าสินค้า",
        "zh-CN": "启用购物车备注",
        "zh-TW": "啟用購物車備註"
      },
      "default": false
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! You are an absolute legend mate!